# Cakephp and iOS 10.3.2

Tags: php, ios, cakephp

Since the new iOS update (10.3.2), we can't reach our website from an Apple device. Safari, Chrome or Firefox are returning a blank page or an error page saying there's a network problem.

We've tried from different places, different kind of iphones, on wifi or cell connection (3G,4G)

On mine it was working well, so I updated it to the 10.3.2 version, and I'm having the same error.

I tried contacting my web host but they told me they couldn't do anything. I tried to install Cakephp in a subdirectory, but even with a fresh install and an empty cakephp (2.9.8), it doesn't work.

I tried the same thing with a Cakephp 3 installation, and it works.

I tried installing Cakephp 2.9.8 on another web hosting (a personal one from the same web host) and .. it works.

So I'm getting a little confused as it seems to be an issue with :

- iOS 10.3.2
- Cakephp 2.9.2 to 2.9.8
- my web hosting

Does anybody can give me any direction to look up ? I'm starting to be really depressed here ...

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary solution by changing my web hosting configuration.

My web host (OVH, French host) allows to use PHP-FPM (which is a PHP FastCGI implementation) to enhance the website performance.

When I disabled it yesterday, my website was available for iOS 10.3.2 users ! I don't know why, but for now I'm relieved.

I've just asked OVH if they have any idea why, but I'm not really optimistic about their reply ...